# What Is The Correct Way To Comment in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

The Way I comment seems to be messing with my script, or just skips past the commented ones, why does it do this and what is the 'safe way' to comment?

Example 1:

`COUNT(*) AS "NumberOfUsers" -- Count Number Of Users`

Example 2:

`COUNT(*) AS "NumberOfUsers" /* Count Number Of Users */`

Example 3:

```
COUNT(*) AS "NumberOfUsers" 
-- Count Number Of Users
```

Should I be commenting on my SQL script at all?

Comment: Both are valid ways of commenting in SQL which one you prefer is a matter of taste

Comment: If you have issues that lines seem to be skipped, maybe you need to show a sample script. Also how are you executing it? (Wild guess) may there be a problem with end-of-lines, that causes the intended end of a -- comment to be missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should I be commenting on my SQL script at all?

The general answer is "yes".  However, this comment is useless:

```
COUNT(*) AS "NumberOfUsers" 
-- Count Number Of Users
```

It is best to write code that is clear.  And you have named `COUNT(*)` clearly, so no comment is necessary.

Where do you want to use comments?  Here are examples of useful comments:

- `-- A LEFT JOIN is needed because not all users have apps`
- `-- Intentionally using UNION to remove duplicates`
- `-- COALESCE() is needed because the value can be NULL !  We may need to fix the data.`

A comment that says:

```
COUNT(*)  -- count the number of matching rows
```

**is not useful**.  Anyone who understands basic SQL knows what this is doing.

We just had this conversation with my group at work.  Comments should be adding information that is not obvious in the code.

Comment: The example is irrelevant here, I'll try rephrasing, my main concern was, the comments seem to be effecting the script and making it skip lines, I tried searching for it but no one else seems to have come across this problem

Comment: @GentianGashi . . . It is just ironic to me that we had a discussion about a very similar comment.  Simply naming the variable correctly eliminates the need for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your example is correct and it is good practice of doing comment in sql script.

- `--` is used for single line comment.
- `/* */` is used for multiple line comments.

Comment is generally given before logic.

Something like:

```
/* Count Number Of Users */
Count(*) AS "NumberOfUsers"
```

Or single line comment can be given after expression as following for good readability:

```
Count(*) AS "NumberOfUsers" -- Count Number Of Users
```

Cheers!!

Comment: I thought so but my scripts aren't running with the comments, I'm using SQL Plus in Oracle

Comment: @GentianGashi an example of what isn't working would be helpful. The only case I can think of that might cause a SQL\*Plus script not to work would be where you place a comment on the same line as a terminating `;` or `/` character, as SQL terminator characters need to be on a line on their own.

Answer (score 1):

Commenting basics:

- -- for single line comments
- /* (start comment) */ (end comment)

You should comment your SQL, but try to do it in a usefull way.

- What does my Query do?
- Is there something special about my Query?
- etc.